# Ansible seems to be ignoring variable in when conditional when it is overridden with "-e" from the command line

Tags: python, ansible

I'm working on an Ansible playbook that uses a when condition, and I was trying to test the scenario where there is a default value specified as a play variable, which can then be selectively overridden from the command line using the -e argument to ansible-playbook. But this is not working as I would expect, and I'm not seeing any obvious reason(s) why.

Here's the setup (this is a super stripped-down sample, just to show the point, not my real playbook).

conditional_task.yml

```yaml
    - name: A playbook to conditionally print some debug messages
      hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: False
      vars:
        doomed: False
      tasks:
        - name: print the value of doomed
          debug: var=doomed
        - name: print the message if we're doomed
          debug:
            msg: "We're f*****g doomed!"
          when: doomed == True
        - name: print the message if we're not doomed
          debug:
            msg: "Glory be to FSM, we are saved!"
          when: doomed == False
```

If I run this with the ansible-playbook command with no arguments, I get exactly the expected output.

```
    $ ansible-playbook conditional_task.yml
    
    PLAY [A playbook to conditionally print some debug messages] ************************************************************************************
    
    TASK [print the value of doomed] ****************************************************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "doomed": true
    }
    
    TASK [print the message if we're doomed] ********************************************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "We're f*****g doomed!"
    }
    
    TASK [print the message if we're not doomed] ****************************************************************************************************
    skipping: [localhost]
    
    PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************
    localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And if I edit the playbook to change the value of the doomed var to False, and re-run this, I get the other message.

```
$ ansible-playbook conditional_task.yml

PLAY [A playbook to conditionally print some debug messages] ************************************************************************************

TASK [print the value of doomed] ****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "doomed": false
}

TASK [print the message if we're doomed] ********************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [print the message if we're not doomed] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Glory be to FSM, we are saved!"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Now, given all that, I would expect to be able to do something like this:

```
$ ansible-playbook -e doomed=False conditional_task.yml
```

and get the "not doomed" message. What I get instead is this:

```
$ ansible-playbook -e doomed=False conditional_task.yml

PLAY [A playbook to conditionally print some debug messages] ************************************************************************************

TASK [print the value of doomed] ****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "doomed": false
}

TASK [print the message if we're doomed] ********************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [print the message if we're not doomed] ****************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

As you can see, *neither* when condition fires in this case. It's almost like the variable isn't there at all, or has some unexpected value, or something. But as the debug output shows, the variable *is* defined, and does have value "false" as expected. And yet the "when" conditionals ignore this.

It also doesn't matter if I change the command line to

```
$ ansible-playbook -e doomed=True conditional_task.yml
```

In that case I still get neither conditional task executing. But again, the debug statement shows that doomed is present and has value of "true".

I also tried re-writing my conditions as "doomed is true" and "doomed is false" respectively, instead of using the == operator and that didn't make any difference. At this point I'm stuck. If anybody can explain this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my Ansible version information:

```
$ ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.10.8
  config file = /extradrive1/development/experimental/ansible/ansible_experimental/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/prhodes/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.9.7 (default, Sep 10 2021, 14:59:43) [GCC 11.2.0]
```

This is all running on Pop! OS:

```
NAME="Pop!_OS"
VERSION="21.10"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that the type of the extra variables passed to Ansible from the command line is always **string**. For example, the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    doomed: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: doomed|type_debug
    - debug:
        msg: We are doomed
      when: doomed
```

works as expected. The type of the variable *doomed* is Boolean. Then, simply use the variable in the condition. No comparison is needed. The debug task will be skipped

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  doomed|type_debug: bool

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
```

The thing will change when you pass the variable from the command line. Now, the type of the variable *doomed* is a string. A non-empty string will evaluate to *True* in the condition and the debug task will be executed

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e doomed=false

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  doomed|type_debug: str

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: We are doomed
```

There is a simple universal solution. **Always cast such variables to bool**.  In addition to this, to simplify the code, [*default*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.default) to *false* or *true*, depending on the use-case, instead of an explicit declaration. This way you write the code fast and the condition will always do what you want

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: We are doomed
      when: doomed|d(false)|bool
```

Comment: Heh. Between the time I posted this, and the time I got home, it occurred to me that "this is probably a type conversion issue".  So yeah, what you're saying makes perfect sense now, realizing that the command line vars are always sent as type "string".  Thanks a ton, @Vladimir!